# How to simply deploy Java/JavaFX applicartion on Max OS?

Tags: java, macos, javafx, deployment

I designed a Java application with some JavaFX features, whose ideal target is the Java 8 JRE. The application works fine, and has to be ran on several OS, like Windows, Mac OS or Linux.

The application is designed with Eclipse and JavaFX scene builder.

Thought I manage in installing manually it on Mac OS, I would need a more automated process for end-users: so far, I must copy the files, run a JRE installer if needed and finally launch the application.

Now what I need is some kind of script that would do the job in one click:
- Check whether the appropriate JRE is available or not
- Install or upgrade the appropriate JRE
- Copy the needed files
- Set a shortcut on the desktop
- Launch the application.

Does anybody know which tool I should try ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you can use the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javafxpackager.html) tool.

Comment: And if you want to use the latest JavaFX and JDK you can follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@adam_carroll/java-packager-with-jdk11-31b3d620f4a8